# Saving FormData in .NET Core with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I'm trying to save a form with Angular 7, it contains both files and regular data.

I'm using this to send the request

```
saveCitaBeneficio(cita: Cita) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (var prop in cita) {
        formData.append(prop, cita[prop]);
    }

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    return this.http.post(`/api/BeneficiosOnline`, formData, { headers: headers });
}
```

And this is the endpoint I'm calling

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]CitaWebDto cita)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _helper.SaveCitaBeneficioOnline(cita);
            return StatusCode(201, result);
        }
        return BadRequest(cita);
    }
```

When using Postman it works just fine, however sending this form data all I see on the backend is a null object, on the network tab I can see that data is actually being sent:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybalyvAXgvHxSi7VH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="correoElectronico"

test@test.com
```

I've tried setting the Content-Disposition header as well, I've tried not specifying any header, I've tried not adding the [FromForm] decorator, but I can't seem to get anything but an empty object.

Edit:

I now notice that even though I'm changing the Content-Type header before sending, Chrome Network still shows as application/json, am I setting it wrong?

[image: Chrome Network showing application/json Content-Type]

Comment: At first, I see a misprint - "mulipart/form-data" instead of  "multipart/form-data".

Comment: @kogonidze I hadn't noticed that, however after fixing it it still isn't working, I notice now looking at the Network  tab in Chrome that the Content-Type is still application/json, even after setting it

Comment: just avoid setting header. It may be interpret automatically based on formdata.

Comment: One more suggestion is that , there is issue with accept as well. Try to look at postman request.

Comment: @dotnetstep even if I don't set the header it shows up as "application/json" in the network tab, and just an empty object in the backend

Answer (score 0):

> trying to save a form with Angular 7, it contains both files and regular data.

To post `formdata` object from Angular frontend to API backend, you can refer to the following working sample.

```
saveCitaBeneficio(cita: Cita) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (var prop in cita) {
    formData.append(prop, cita[prop]);
  }

  return this.http.post(
    `https://xxx/api/BeneficiosOnline`,
    formData
  );
}
```

*Interface Cita*

```
interface Cita {
  correoElectronico: string;
  img?: File;
}
```

*Call function with testing data*

```
this.saveCitaBeneficio({
  correoElectronico: 'test@test.com',
  img: this.fileToUpload
}).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Success!');
});
```

*Model and action method*

```
public class CitaWebDto
{
    public string CorreoElectronico { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Img { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] CitaWebDto cita)
{
    //...
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: `When using Postman it works just fine, however sending this form data all I see on the backend is a null object` To troubleshoot the issue, please doublecheck the actual request and posted data in browser developer tool Network tab and compare it with the working request that you sent from postman.

Comment: is unneccesary use formData you can send a simple json object